# Merge 'eee', 'eeepc' with the 'eee-pc' tag on Super User

Tags: discussion, status-completed, retag-request

The trademark is "Eee PC", so I assume the one with the hyphen is the best candidate to be the canonical tag. There are only three affected questions, so this one should be easy.

All glory to [Joakim Elofsson](https://superuser.com/questions/14037/is-it-just-me-or-the-eeepcs-wireless-is-woefully-underpowered) for finding this one.

Answer (score 11):

Going with **eee-pc**

There are at least some SuperUser users over the 500 rep mark, which would mean they'd be able to retag them into the same eee-pc box.